# Plot subplots from xarray Dataset to AxesGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray

Map subplots can be created directly from a `xarray.Dataset` in this way: (taken from the second example [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#maps))

```py
p = air.isel(time=[0, 4]).plot(
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    col="time",
    subplot_kws={"projection": ccrs.Orthographic(-80, 35)})


for ax in p.axes.flat:
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.gridlines()
```

However, this corresponds to using standard `matplotlib` subplots, while it would be nice for example to pass an `AxesGrid` to the `plot` function, to have more control on the subplots initially. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your custom axis to xarray plot function via the `ax` argument to have more control over the way you define the axis.

```
map_projection = ccrs.Orthographic(-80, 35)
fig, axis = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8,8), dpi=100, subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_projection))


for i,ax in enumerate(axis.flatten()):
    air.isel(time=i).plot(ax=ax,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Comment: I have specified in my post that I don't want to use standard subplots, but an `AxesGrid`

Comment: ok, what exactly do you want to control? for example, it is possible to create a grid using `gridspec` for finer adjustments and add axes to the grids, that can also include axes with cartopy projections